# Implementing a Push Notifications server : How to check that a message passing the device token came from the real device?

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I am adding push notifications to an existing ios app. Users should be able to register to be notified of events that occur relating to different news topics.
At the moment we don't require the user to log in.

The simple approach seems to be for the app to send the device token to the server in a message along with details of the events they wish to receive notifications about.

**But doesn't this mean that malicious users could set up/view/delete notifications for other user's devices? Either by finding out their device ID somehow or simply trying random device IDs?**

How do others deal with this issue?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to require a login for changes.

You are thinking right, a malicious user does not need to use your app, they can construct their own code, this is missed by many developers.

Comment: Thanks Zaph - Imagining that I do set up user accounts to manage notifications... If the first user account to use a certain device token is the only one that can create, edit and delete notifications, doesn't that mean that the user could never switch accounts for the app on a particular device? Or alternatively, if I let any user create notifications for the device, but only let users edit and delete their own notifications, a malicious person could still create lots of notifications for a particular device, right?